# Weird behaviour of exception handling on reading something from file

Tags: java, file-io, exception

I am trying to read from a file, however I get some weird results. Below is my code.

```
    class A
    {
            try{
                    B writeToFile = new B();
                                B readFromFile = new B();
                                File file = new File("C:/Users/HB/workspace/A/src/xyz.txt");
                                boolean fileExists = file.isFile();
                                if (fileExists)
                                {
                                    readFromFile.readFromFile();
                                }
                                if(...) 
                                {
                                      //my other code
                                }
                                else

                        throw new Exception (type_op); 
                }
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
            System.out.println("Incorrect number of arguments supplied to command.");
            System.out.println("");

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
            System.out.printf("'%s' is not a valid command.%n",type_op);
            System.out.println();
    }
```

What I am doing here is Class A is the main class where I am performing all the operations. There are certain operations I am performing, and if user enters operations other than those than above exceptions are thrown. On debugging, I see the file xyz.txt is found, and compiler goes into the readFromFile(). However, there in the while loop, it checks for the data inside the file and then throws me an exception -

```
'operation_inputted_on_console' is not a valid command.
```

I expected it to read from the file, and store it in my arrayList.

```
    class B
    {
    public void readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
            Scanner inputStream = null;
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/HB/workspace/A/src/xyz.txt"));
            while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
            {
                attribute1=inputStream.next();
                attribute2=inputStream.next();
                attribute3=inputStream.next();
                attribute4=inputStream.nextInt();
                attribute5=inputStream.nextInt();
                attribute6=inputStream.nextInt();
                attribute7=inputStream.nextInt();
                addPlayer(attribute1,attribute2,attribute3...);
            }
            inputStream.close();

    }
    public void writeToFile() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
            PrintWriter outputStreamName = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/HB/workspace/A/src/xyz.txt",true));
            int size = arrayList.size();
            B obj;
            //my code
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                //my code
            }
            outputStreamName.close();

        }
    }
    }
```

Above code works fine if I remove readFromFile() from my class. Something is wrong in readFromFile over here which is causing this issue.

xyz.txt contains below --

```
a,a,a,2,0,2,0
b,b,b,2,2,0,0
c,c,c,2,1,1,0
a,a,a,1,0,1,0
b,b,b,1,1,0,0
```

Comment: //my code? what is in there?

Comment: In your `Exception` handlers, please print your stack-trace - e.g. `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - added code snippet.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - why do I need to use printStackTrace()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse a one line string using next and nextInt that resulted to `InputMismatchException` which should expect a space between them without commas.

example:

```
a a a 2 0 2 0
```

using the above example you can fully use the code inside your 
while statement, but since you have commas you need to split it using the split method

using your sample in the txt file

```
while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
        {
            string[] line =inputStream.nextLine().split(",");
            string firstLetter = line[0];
            string secondLetter = line[1];
            string thriedLetter = line[2];
            int firstNumber = String.parseInt(line[3]);
            int secondNumber = String.parseInt(line[4]);
            int thriedNumber = String.parseInt(line[5]);
             int fourthNumber = String.parseInt(line[6]);
        }
```

using the above code you can now succesfully parse it with commas